# Screenly install process

Tags: omxplayer, osmc

I recently got a Raspberry Pi, and I would like to use it as an advertising media player. My research led me to Screenly but now I want to know if I have install the OS first and repeat the same copy image file to install Screenly on the device.

Answer (score 0):

To install [Screenly OSE](https://www.screenly.io/ose/) using their custom image, you don't need to install an OS first. Just follow their instructions to install the image, which will *overwrite* any other operating systems you have on your SD card.

> The by far quickest way to get started with Screenly OSE is to download our custom image. The image is really nothing but a regular Raspbian Wheezy-installation with Screenly installed per the instructions below.

As the document states, the image **includes** Raspbian Wheezy (which is rather outdated, I might add), so you do not need to install an OS first.

Comment: No problem; you can [mark this as accepted](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if this works, otherwise just let me know below.